# How to filter first letter in a button using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

How to make the button functional, and the button has default value, for example button A-B has a range for a to b of first letter to be filter. Thanks, Sorry for my last post, it was hard to understand. =)

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.filter('startsWithLetter', function () {
    return function (items, letter) {
        var filtered = [];
        var letterMatch = new RegExp(letter, 'i');
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = items[i];
            if (letterMatch.test(item.name.substring(0, 1))) {
                filtered.push(item);
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    };
});

app.controller('PersonCtrl', function () {
    this.friends = [{
        name: 'Andrew'        
    }, {
        name: 'Baldo'
    }, {
        name: 'Carlo'
    }, {
        name: 'Delo'
    }, {
        name: 'Emman'
    }, {
        name: 'Ferman'
    }];
});
```

```css
</style>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.7/angular.js"></script>
<style>
```

```html
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="PersonCtrl as person">
        <input type="text" ng-model="letter" placeholder="Enter a letter to filter">
        <button>A-B</button>
        <button>C-D</button>
        <button>E-F</button>
      
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="friend in person.friends | startsWithLetter:letter">
                {{ friend }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the point you ask? If you want to ask the way to implement some filter, you should remove other elements in your html, javascript and your question. BTW at first, Could you setup plunker or something in which you write as less as possible to clear the point you ask.

Comment: @yazaki can you help me how to do this? Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you meant? Did you want clicking each button to filter by those 2 letters?

All I changed was set the markup for the buttons to be:

```
<button ng-click="letter='[AB]'">A-B</button>
<button ng-click="letter='[CD]'">C-D</button>
<button ng-click="letter='[EF]'">E-F</button>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.filter('startsWithLetter', function () {
    return function (items, letter) {
        var filtered = [];
        var letterMatch = new RegExp(letter, 'i');
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = items[i];
            if (letterMatch.test(item.name.substring(0, 1))) {
                filtered.push(item);
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    };
});

app.controller('PersonCtrl', function () {
    this.friends = [{
        name: 'Andrew'        
    }, {
        name: 'Baldo'
    }, {
        name: 'Carlo'
    }, {
        name: 'Delo'
    }, {
        name: 'Emman'
    }, {
        name: 'Ferman'
    }];
});
```

```css
</style>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.7/angular.js"></script>
<style>
```

```html
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="PersonCtrl as person">
        <input type="text" ng-model="letter" placeholder="Enter a letter to filter">
        <button ng-click="letter='[AB]'">A-B</button>
        <button ng-click="letter='[CD]'">C-D</button>
        <button ng-click="letter='[EF]'">E-F</button>
      
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="friend in person.friends | startsWithLetter:letter">
                {{ friend }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for saving my project =). This is what I looking for.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Don't forget to accept the answer and, optionally, upvote it if it answered your question.

Comment: can you help me again. This is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313331/filter-first-letter-doesnt-work-in-angularjs