# Filter first letter doesn't work in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Last time i have posted my problem here  how filter the first letter in a data, and someone helped me on how to do it. But when I try to add it to my project I don't know where I put the  startsWithA filter function to the ng-repeat that filtered the data. Any idea how fix it? Thanks again.

```js
<script>
 var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
 
    $scope.student = [{
           name: 'Andrew'        
       }, {
           name: 'Butler'
       }, {
           name: 'Cameron'
       }, {
           name: 'Delo'
       },
                   {
           name: 'Emman'
       },
                   {
           name: 'Ferbs'
       }];
 
 app.filter('startFrom', function()
 { 
   return function(input, start) 
   {
    if(input) 
   {
     start = +start; //parse to int
      return input.slice(start);
    }
    return [];
   }
 });

 app.controller('customersCrtl', function ($scope, $timeout)
    {  
  
     $scope.list = student; 
     $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
     $scope.entryLimit = 10; //max no of items to display in a page
     $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter
     $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;

    

    
    $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) 
    {
     $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
    };
    
    $scope.filter = function() 
    {
     $timeout(function() 
     {
      $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
     }, 10);

    
    };
    
    
    $scope.sort_by = function(predicate) 
    {
     $scope.predicate = predicate;
     $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    }; 

    
  
 });
 
 app.filter('startsWithA', function () {
     return function (letter,items) {
         var filtered = [];
         var letterMatch = new RegExp(letter, 'i');
         for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
             var item = items[i];
             if (letterMatch.test(item.name.substring(0, 1))) {
                 filtered.push(item);
             }
         }
         return filtered;
     };
 });
 
</script>
```

```css
</style>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.7/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<style>
```

```html
<div class="container" ng-controller="customersCrtl">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
  <h2 id="titleHead"><center>Student List</center></h2>
  </div>
        <div class="option-panel">
          <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
             <form class="navbar-form">
                  <div class="input-group">
                     <input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-click="filter()" placeholder="Search student" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
                  </div>
              </form>
         </div>         
        </div>
   <div class="nav navbar-default"> 
      <div class="tab-panel">
           <nav>
           <ul>
             <li class="active" name = "active"><a ng-click="letter = [AB]">A-B</a>  </li>
                    <li class="active" name = "active"><a ng-click="letter = [CD]">C-D</a>  </li>
                    <li class="active" name = "active"><a ng-click="letter = [EF]">E-F</a>  </li>
                   
            
          </ul>
          </nav>
       </div>
      </div>  
        <div id="no-more-tables">
            <table class="col-md-12 table-bordered table-condensed cf" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">
          <thead class="cf">
           <tr>
            
            <th><center>Name&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('first_name');"></a></center></th>
           
           </tr>
          </thead>      
          <tbody color="#">       
           <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search |orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit |startWithA:letter limitTo:entryLimit ">      
            <td data-title="Name" class="text-center">{{data.name}}</td>
    
                      
           </tr> 
          </tbody>             
         </table>
          <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems == 0">
          <div class="col-md-12">
             <center><h4>No results found</h4></center>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">
         <center><div pagination="" page="currentPage" on-select-page="setPage(page)" boundary-links="true" total-items="filteredItems" items-per-page="entryLimit" class="pagination-small" previous-text="&laquo;" next-text="&raquo;"></div></center>  
      </div>        
         </div>
         
</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Im not clear what exactly it is that you want...

Comment: I just want to know where in ng-repeat I put the startWithA : letter for the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing:

1. customerCrtl (js) -> customerCtrl (html)
2. startsWithA (js) -> startWithA (html)
3. missing "|" before limitTo (html)

I found the problem is that you aren't escaping the letters in the ng-clicks:

```
ng-click="letter = [AB]"
```

You need:

```
ng-click="letter = '[AB]'"
```

`$scope.letters` always is `[null]`. `[AB]` evaluates to `[null]` because `$scope.AB` is not defined. And then when you try to use the `startsWithA` filter when `$scope.letters` is `[null]` you never return any filtered items.

I got the snippet working below.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

var student = [{
  name: 'Andrew'
}, {
  name: 'Butler'
}, {
  name: 'Cameron'
}, {
  name: 'Delo'
}, {
  name: 'Emman'
}, {
  name: 'Ferbs'
}];

app.filter('startFrom', function() {
  return function(input, start) {
    if (input) {
      start = +start; //parse to int
      return input.slice(start);
    }
    return [];
  }
});

app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

  $scope.list = student;
  $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
  $scope.entryLimit = 10; //max no of items to display in a page
  $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter
  $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;

  $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
    $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
  };

  $scope.filter = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
    }, 10);
  };


  $scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
    $scope.predicate = predicate;
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
  };



});

app.filter('startsWithA', function() {
  return function(items, letter) {
    console.log(items, letter)
    var filtered = [];
    var letterMatch = new RegExp(letter, 'i');
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var item = items[i];
      if (letterMatch.test(item.name.substring(0, 1))) {
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    }
    console.log(filtered);
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h2 id="titleHead"><center>Student List</center></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="option-panel">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
          <form class="navbar-form">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-click="filter()" placeholder="Search student" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="nav navbar-default">
        <div class="tab-panel">
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li class="active" name="active"><a ng-click="letter = '[AB]'">A-B</a> 
              </li>
              <li class="active" name="active"><a ng-click="letter = '[CD]'">C-D</a> 
              </li>
              <li class="active" name="active"><a ng-click="letter = '[EF]'">E-F</a> 
              </li>


            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="no-more-tables">
        <table class="col-md-12 table-bordered table-condensed cf" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">
          <thead class="cf">
            <tr>

              <th>
                <center>Name&nbsp;
                  <a ng-click="sort_by('first_name');"></a>
                </center>
              </th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody color="#">
            <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search |orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit |startsWithA:letter |limitTo:entryLimit ">
              <td data-title="Name" class="text-center">{{data.name}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems == 0">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <center>
              <h4>No results found</h4>
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">
          <center>
            <div pagination="" page="currentPage" on-select-page="setPage(page)" boundary-links="true" total-items="filteredItems" items-per-page="entryLimit" class="pagination-small" previous-text="&laquo;" next-text="&raquo;"></div>
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks now its working, but when I convert my data from fetching using $http in angular. It doesn't working again.

Comment: I think you should probably put more of the logic in the controller or a service rather than having a huge filter, order, limitTo, startsWithA expression. That would make the code a lot easier to comprehend.

Comment: Do you know some tutorial or links that similar to my problem, fetching data in $http?, But thank you again, if you didn't fix my codes I will never realize that the problem was on $http service.